# A committee should be selected from 8 men and 6 women.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A committee consisting of 4 men and 4 women is to be selected from a group of 8 men and 6 women.

a) Find the number of different ways in which the committee can be selected.

b) Suppose that such a committee was selected. Find the number of different ways in which those committee members can be seated in a row if no two women can be seated next to each other

My Attempt -

1. ${8}\choose{4}$ $\times$ ${6}\choose{4}$ $ =1050$
2. Since we have 4 men and 4 women,

$$4\times4\times3\times3\times2\times2 =576$$

Is there a different method to think the last part

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the second part. You have to take two cases MFMFMFMF and FMFMFMFM separately. Your method accounts for only one case.

Comment: (a) The answer is $nCr(8,4)×nCr(6,4)=1050$. Your $1^{st}$ answer is correct.

Comment: @ShreyaMundhada There is also the cases FMMFMFMF, FMFMMFMF, and FMFMFMMF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your first answer is correct, the second one is not. Here's one way to solve to second part.

We start with the number of ways in which we can seat the 4 men. That's 4!.

Now, when talking about the women, we have a restriction. No two of them can sit together. So, we address this condition as follow.

$$\times \, M \times M \times M \times M \,\times$$

What you see above is a representation of the 4 men sitting in a row (something we have taken care of earlier). Now, we can use the position indicated by $\times$ marks to seat the women. That way, there will always be at least one man between two women - as necessitated by the question.

So, we have 5 positions to seat 4 women. This can be dome in $^5P\,_4$ ways.

Hence, the total number of ways is

$$
\begin{align*}
4! \,\times \,^5P\,_4 &= 2880
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another method for the second question (no case-work):
Let $g_i$ denote the no. of people sitting between the $i$th and $(i-1)$th woman (or the *gap*). $g_1$ can be 0 or 1 (assuming there is a position 0), while $g_2,g_3,g_4$ are all positive. Add another variable $g_5$ that can be 0 or 1 (remaining spaces at the end). Then you have:
$$g_1+g_2+g_3+g_4+g_5 + 4 = 8 \implies g_1+(g_2-1)+(g_3-1)+(g_4-1)+g_5 = 1$$
By using $g_i-1$, we have eliminated the positive condition. By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the number of solutions to this is $\binom{5}{4}$. Now, you can permute the four women and 4 men in $4!\times 4!$ was giving a total of $\color{green}{2880}$.

---

**Remark:** Although the utility of this method isn't obvious here, it is more useful when you have larger numbers and specific conditions on the gaps.

Answer (score -1):

Your first answer is right.
But for second one I think you missed many cases.

Soo I think it can be solved by this way

Number of ways all can be sited - **$8!$**

**CASE 1**
$-$ When all women are sitting together - **$5!$**

**CASE 2**
$-$ When only three women are sitting together - **$6!-5!$** (Removing all cases when all four women are sitting together.)

**CASE 3**
$-$ When women in group of 2-2 are sitting - **$7!-5!$** (Removing all cases when all four women are sitting together.)

Soo answer can be
$$8!-7!+5!-6!+5!-5! = 34680$$

Answer (score -2):

Your answer for the second part is also correct. The number of ways to arrange 4 men in a row is 4!=24
and the number of ways to arrange 4 women in a row is also 4!=24
. However, since no two women can be seated next to each other, we have to place the women in the gaps between the men or at the ends of the row. There are 5 such gaps, so the number of ways to choose 4 gaps out of 5 is (45​)=5
. Therefore, the number of ways to seat the committee members is 24×24×5=2880
.
There is another method to think about the last part, using the principle of inclusion-exclusion. We can count the total number of ways to seat the 8 committee members in a row, which is 8!=40320
, and then subtract the number of ways that have at least one pair of women next to each other. To do this, we can group any two women together and treat them as one unit, and then arrange the remaining 7 units in a row. There are (24​)=6
ways to choose the pair of women, and 7!=5040
ways to arrange the 7 units, so the number of ways to have one pair of women next to each other is 6×5040=30240
. However, this also counts the cases where there are two pairs of women next to each other, so we have to add them back. There are (44​)=1
way to choose the two pairs of women, and 6!=720
ways to arrange the 6 units, so the number of ways to have two pairs of women next to each other is 1×720=720
. Therefore, the number of ways to seat the committee members without any pair of women next to each other is 8!−6×7!+1×6!=2880
, which is the same as before